# Equation of state of a universe full electrons

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

If I have a universe full of nothing but (slow moving) electrons, what would the equation of state ($w$, from $p=w\rho$) be? I think it would be incorrect to say that the electrons should be treated as matter (e.g. a pressureless dust w=0) since they interact both gravitationally and via the EM force.

(If it simplifies the problem, we may say instead a universe filled with a spin-0 species of mass $m$ and electric charge $q$.)